# Linux disk partitions

Tags: partition, system-installation, kali-linux

I work with kali. Can I install "/" partition to one disk and "/home" to other? Or should I make home partition on disk with / and mount other disk partition to it? What is the best way?

Comment: yes, you can, nobody prevents you from doing it. Please read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243546/to-secure-my-data-is-it-good-to-have-separate-data-partition-along-with-separa/243549#243549

Comment: So, will it work if I just set /home to other disk? Especially when before home there is windows partition.

Comment: You can put /home wherever you wish. Are you replacing previous Windows partition, or adding new partition on Windows disk for /home?

Comment: Adding to windows disk. I have windows partition and free space for home